# How to check specific value in two metabox?

Tags: metabox, meta-query

Using two arrays in a meta query is not working for me, especially when using the value of second array.

If I remove the value of second array or first or both, then it is working, but I need to check two keys.

If the `$current_player_name` value is present in any of the meta keys, then I need to show the title of the related posts.

Can anybody please tell me the problem of the following code?

```
<?php 
  $current_player_name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'football_team_team_name', true );

    $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'football_fixture',
        'meta_query' => array(

                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                            'key' => 'pb_responsible_home_person',
                           'value' => $current_player_name 

                    ),
                    array(
                            'key' => 'pb_responsible_away_person',
                            'value' => $current_player_name 

                    ),

        )// meta query end 
    );//$args end

 $player_query = null;
    $player_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>


<!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $player_query->have_posts() ) : $player_query->the_post(); ?>
        <ol>

            <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
        </ol>


    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the meta_compare argument to the meta query . Now your code will be like :

```
 'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                                'key' => 'pb_responsible_home_person',
                               'value' => $current_player_name,
                               'compare' => '='

                        ),
                        array(
                                'key' => 'pb_responsible_away_person',
                                'value' => $current_player_name,
                                 'compare' => '='

                        ),

            )// meta query end
```

EDIT

$current_player_name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'football_team_team_name', true );

```
    $m_keys =array('pb_responsible_home_person','pb_responsible_away_person')

    $meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');

    foreach ($m_keys as $m_key) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => $m_key,
            'value' => $current_player_name,
            'compare' => '='
        );
    }

    $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'football_fixture',
       'meta_query' => $meta_query
    );
```

Try this, working when i checked locally

Comment: It shows error as:Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-meta-query.php on line 597

Comment: @bdtheme - try the new edit . It is working for me when I checked locally.

Comment: Is second line will be closed with semicolon: like as :$m_keys =array('pb_responsible_home_person','pb_responsible_away_person');

Comment: if so then it shows following :Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-meta-query.php on line 597

Comment: Which version of wordpress are you using?

Comment: why?Could you please explain?

Comment: I had tested both codes in my local server and it's working good.

Comment: 4.6.1 version...

Comment: Me too have 4.6.1 and it's working..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47646/discussion-between-bdtheme-and-unnikrishnan-r).